# Why doesn't Thymeleaf show me the number of products from my database?

Tags: thymeleaf

Please help me clarify a problem with Thymeleaf.
I work on an application that sells several types of household appliances, phones.
In the database I have several types of Samsung brand products: refrigerators, washing machines, telephones.
I want from the code to be able to count the refrigerators in the database, the Samsung brand and their number to appear to the user in the browser.
I work with Spring Boot, in Intellij Community and MySQL.

In the Repository, I created the following method:

```
@Query(value="select count(*) from products where name='Frigider' and brand='Samsung' ",                  nativeQuery = true)
    Integer findNumberOfSamsungFridges();
```

In the Controller, I created the following method:

```
@GetMapping("/number/samsung/fridges")
    public ModelAndView numberOfSamsungFridges(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("products");
        int numSamsungFridges = productRepository.findNumberOfSamsungFridges();
        modelAndView.addObject("samsungNumber", numSamsungFridges);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

and in the html page, where I created the code for the appearance of these products, I wrote next to the Samsung button, which should take me to the appearance of the cards with the Samsung refrigerators, the following code:

```
<button class="…" style="background-color: #048ed8">
        Samsung(<span th:text="${samsungNumber}"></span>)
     </button>
```

In the browser window, the user should see the Samsung button, followed by the number corresponding to the number of Samsung refrigerators in the database, that is:

Samsung(8)

But after I run the code, in the browser, it only appears:

Samsung()

I mention that everything seems to be fine:

- in the database, I have the 8 Samsung brand refrigerators;
- if I run in Mysql, the query:

```
select count(*) from products where name='Fridge' and brand='Samsung';
```

it works properly and I count the 8 Samsung refrigerators from the database;
-thymeleaf works, because with its help, I create my cards and bring them into the browser.
But I can't figure out what I did wrong.
Why doesn't the corresponding number appear in my browser, as I stated above?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you use a debugger to check if `numSamsungFridges` in your controller has the number `8`? (Or just log it to the console or something)

Comment: I know for sure that the number of refrigerators in the database is 8.
When I run the query in MySql Workbench, it displays the number 8.
It's a problem on the Repository – Controller – Thymeleaf route, I think it's more like Thymeleaf.
It does not receive the data transmitted from the Controller or does not transmit it to the browser.
But for now I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I changed the Repository method:

```
@Query(value="select * from products where name='Fridge' and 
brand='Samsung'", nativeQuery = true)
List<ProductEntity> findNumberOfSamsungFridges();
```

and I added one more:

```
@Query(value="select * from products where name='Fridge' limit 0, 9", 
nativeQuery = true)
List<ProductEntity> findBFridge1(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
```

I changed the method in the Controller. Now it looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/URL to fetch page products.html")
public ModelAndView bFridge1(){
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("products");
List<ProductEntity> numSamsungFridges = 
productRepository.findNumberOfSamsungFridges();
modelAndView.addObject("productListB1", 
productRepository.findBFridge1("keyword"));
modelAndView.addObject("samsungNumber", numSamsungFridges.size());
return modelAndView;
```

}

and in the html page, it remained the same:

```
<button class="..." style="background-color: #048ed8">
Samsung(<span th:text="${samsungNumber}"></span>)
</button>
```

I have multiple product pages. Each page contains 9 product cards.
On the first page, where I want to display the 9 product cards, I also display the information in a corner:

Samsung(8)

So, I brought from the database the 8 refrigerators that interested me.
I also brought the 9 product cards on the first page.
In the Controller, I assembled the 2 pieces of information and displayed them in the browser.
Now it is working.